# Pytorch model do not update weights

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to solve the CartPole problem with pytorch, but after several iterations the parameters don't update.

The code that I'm trying to reproduce is this one [cartpole https://github.com/gsurma/cartpole/blob/master/cartpole.py] made in keras.

```
import random
from collections import deque

import gym
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

GAMMA = 0.95

MEMORY_SIZE = 1000000
BATCH_SIZE = 50

EXPLORATION_MAX = 1.0
EXPLORATION_MIN = 0.01
EXPLORATION_DECAY = 0.995


# Principal Neural Netword module
class DQNSolver(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, observation_space, action_space):
        super(DQNSolver, self).__init__()
        self.action_space = action_space
        self.observation_space = observation_space

        self.hiddenSpace = 24

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.observation_space, self.hiddenSpace)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(self.hiddenSpace, self.action_space)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.fc1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out


class cartpole():

    def __init__(self):

        # Device configuration
        device = torch.device('cpu' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

        self.env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")
        self.observation_space = self.env.observation_space.shape[0]
        self.action_space = self.env.action_space.n

        self.dqn_solver = DQNSolver(self.observation_space, self.action_space).to(device)

        # Create the memory
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=MEMORY_SIZE)
        self.exploration_rate = EXPLORATION_MAX

        # Create the optimizer and the loss
        self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.dqn_solver.parameters(), lr=0.1)
        self.loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss()

    def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

    # This custom function will receive a observation of the state of the
    # environment, and then return the action
    def predict_action(self, observation):
        # if np.random.rand() < self.exploration_rate:
        #     randomQ = np.random.rand(1, self.action_space)[0]
        #     return np.double(randomQ)
        predicted = self.dqn_solver(observation)
        predicted = predicted.cpu().data.numpy()
        return np.double(predicted)

    def optimize_model(self, state, q_values):
        output = self.predict_action(state)
        output = torch.tensor(output, requires_grad=False)
        qValues = torch.tensor(q_values, requires_grad=True)

        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = self.loss_func(output,  qValues)
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()


        print("Loss: {}".format(loss))

    def experience_replay(self):
        if len(self.memory) < BATCH_SIZE:
            return
        batch = random.sample(self.memory, BATCH_SIZE)
        for state, action, reward, state_next, terminal in batch:
            q_update = reward
            if not terminal:
                next_action = self.predict_action(state_next)
                q_update = (reward + GAMMA * np.amax(next_action))
            q_values = self.predict_action(state)
            q_values[action] = q_update

            self.optimize_model(state, q_values)
        print("Finished replay")
        print('weights after backpropagation = ',   list(self.dqn_solver.parameters()))
        self.exploration_rate *= EXPLORATION_DECAY
        self.exploration_rate = max(EXPLORATION_MIN, self.exploration_rate)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            state = self.env.reset()
            # state = np.reshape(state, [1, self.observation_space])
            state = torch.Tensor(state)
            while True:
                self.env.render()
                action = self.predict_action(state)
                action = np.argmax(action)
                state_next, reward, terminal, info = self.env.step(action)
                reward = reward if not terminal else -reward
                state_next = torch.Tensor(state_next)
                self.remember(state, action, reward, state_next, terminal)
                state = state_next
                if terminal:
                    break
                self.experience_replay()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cartpole().run()
```

after several epochs the parameters printed in this line are the same:

```
print('weights after backpropagation = ',   list(self.dqn_solver.parameters()))
```

also Loss values are closer to a random value, but don't increase or decrease.
What could be wrong?

Comment: Something seems incorrect about how you are converting your predictions (`predicted`) to numpy and then converting it back to a `Tensor` afterward. I think you need to leave it as a Tensor and instead convert `action` to numpy when running the environment.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

In `optimize_model`, you replace the `q_value` with a new tensor, which is not a node of the original computational graph, so the gradients can not be passed back through the network. See the example below,

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

clf = nn.Linear(2, 2)
opt = optim.SGD(clf.parameters(), lr=0.1)
crit = nn.MSELoss()

input = torch.arange(2).float().view(-1, 2)
label = torch.arange(2).float().view(-1, 2)

pred = clf(input)
pred_copy = torch.tensor(pred, requires_grad=True)

opt.zero_grad()
loss_wrong = crit(pred_copy, label)
loss_wrong.backward()
for p in clf.parameters():
    print(p.grad)

opt.zero_grad()
loss_correct = crit(pred, label)
loss_correct.backward()
for p in clf.parameters():
    print(p.grad)
```

Output:

```
None
None
tensor([[-0.0000, -0.5813],
        [-0.0000, -0.9274]])
tensor([-0.5813, -0.9274])
```

From the quick example above, you can see that the gradients computed from the copied prediction can not be passed to the network parameters.

---

### Solution

```
def optimize_model(self, state, q_values):
    output = self.predict_action(state)
    output.requires_grad = False
    qValues.requires_grad = True
```

Besides, as mentioned by @JoshVarty in comments, you shouldn't convert any tensor in the computational graph to numpy and convert it back. That would break the graph, and thus, gradients will not be passed (computed) correctly.

**tl;dr** Only using `Pytorch` built-in functions as possible as you can.